# Binary search function can't find specified numbers if they are at the end or beginning of a sorted array

Tags: c, binary-search, cs50

As the title says above, a binary search function I wrote for some reason can't find the number it was given if it is at the end or beginning of an array. I have tried looking for the issue in the debugger, but nothing strange ever shows up.

For instance if you put in the input `24 25 26 27 28` and the number it was trying to find was 28, it would `return false`.

But if the numbers were `24 25 28 26 30` it would `return true`

(assuming these numbers were already sorted beforehand)

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // check if only 1 item exists in values and if it is the item which is being looked for
    if (n == 1)
    {
        if (value == values[0]) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    int middle = n / 2;

    // if the value is greater than middle, search the right half of the array
    if (value > values[middle])
    {
        // initialize rightHalf since it is a variable length array
        int rightHalf[n];
        for(int x = 0; x <= n; x++) rightHalf[x] = 0;

        int rightHalfSize = n - middle;

        if (value > values[middle])
        {
            int rightHalfSize = n - middle - 1;
            for (int i = 0, m = middle + 1; i < rightHalfSize; i++, m++)
            {
                rightHalf[i] = values[m];
            }
        }
    return search(value, rightHalf, rightHalfSize);
  } // if the value is less than middle, search the left half of the array
    else if (value < values[middle])
    {
        // initialize leftHalf since it is a variable length array
        int leftHalf[n];
        for(int y = 0; y <= n; y++) leftHalf[y] = 0;

        int leftHalfSize = n - middle;

        for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < middle; i++, m++)
        {
            leftHalf[i] = values[m];
        }
    return search(value, leftHalf, leftHalfSize);
  }
    else if (value == values[middle]) return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: A debugger would be very useful for this kind of problem.  You really ought to learn to use one.

Comment: Well the second array you show is *isn't* sorted. A sorted collection is a requirement for binary search. As for your problem, I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: I can't tell what is the exact problem with your code, but on a first glance it looks too complex for a binary search. Is there any specific reason that you tried this instead of simple iterative version?

Comment: @taskinoor I thought it might have been easier to use recursion instead. Would a simpler iterative method be more efficient in this case?

Comment: Yes, iterative version is almost always better than recursive version. And you are doing unnecessary data copy to intermediate arrays. For a simple binary search the only thing you should need is to modify some indices without any data copying to temporary arrays.

Comment: One possible problem is your copying of the values. Why do you do that? Why not simple use the same array (or rather pointer to the arrays first element), and then pass first and last index to search between?

Comment: Okay, thank you guys. I will use a more iterative method instead of using recursion. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear the purpose of creating within the function a variable length array that results in undefined behavior at least due to the loop

```
int rightHalf[n];
for(int x = 0; x <= n; x++) rightHalf[x] = 0;
```

because there is an attempt to change the memory beyond the array for x equal to n.

The function that determines whether the target value is present can be written much simpler.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool search( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    if ( !n )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t middle = n / 2;
        if ( a[middle] < value )
        {
            return search( a + middle + 1, n - middle - 1, value );
        }
        else if ( value < a[middle] )
        {
            return search( a, middle, value );
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "a[0] - 1 is found - %d\n", search( a, N, a[0] - 1 ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "a[%zu] is found - %d\n", i, search( a, N, a[i] ) );

    }

    printf( "a[%zu] + 1 is found - %d\n", N - 1, search( a, N, a[N-1] + 1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[0] - 1 is found - 0
a[0] is found - 1
a[1] is found - 1
a[2] is found - 1
a[3] is found - 1
a[4] is found - 1
a[4] + 1 is found - 0
```